# select the whole <td> on click instead of only the <a> inside of it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

ok here is the thing, I have a table where I have some `<a>`'s, what I want: make clickable the full `<td>` which contains those `<a>`'s.

Pasting my code will explain what I want better

```
<td>
  <a><span>{{:: row.spread.spread}} ({{:: row.spread.moneyLine}})</span></a>
</td>
```

for now the only clickable area is the one with red border

[image]

here my css

```
  td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: get-space(x-small) + 2;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    a {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

ok, all I need is take approach of the full `td` and make them clickable instead of only be able to click over the links, is that clear for you folks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a `display` of `block` on your `<a>` elements, and add the padding those instead. It might also be worthwhile to remove the padding on the `<td>` element:

```
td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;

    a {
      padding: get-space(x-small) + 2;
      display: block;
    }
}
```

If you need to retain the red border, target the `<span>` element:

```
td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;

    a {
      padding: get-space(x-small) + 2;
      display: block;

      span {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: just did it but now I am getting this: http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/15/0226/h_1424984547_3815132_9e4d97c773.png  this is a Bootstrap table

Comment: You need to remove the padding on the `<td>` element. Bootstrap automatically adds it in.